Azure OpenAI, Unable to use deployed model version
Context

I have deployed following models using Azure OpenAi Studio: 

The model could be accessed by using postman for version: 2024-02-15-preview


Issue

I am not able to use the deployed model version. For example although the gpt-4o-mini (version: 2024-07-18) is deployed I am only able to access 2024-02-15-preview



Can you include the endpoint you're calling?

/gpt-4o/chat/completions?api-version=2024-02-15-preview

I had a confusion that the deployed version showed in the Azure open AI service is the actual version which is confusing. So I followed this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/reference to find the exact version

Solved

The version shown in the azure openAI studio cannot be accessed by API which is misleading
Use version mentioned in the GA of this Link

